# Importerror: cannot import name Split

Tags: python, importerror

I am very new to python and need some help here. 
I think it comes from PATH,but I have no clue about fixing it. Please help.

[Once I type in import split and it keeps popping up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDSqq.png)

> runfile('/Users/zhihaowang/Desktop/untitled1.py',
>   wdir='/Users/zhihaowang/Desktop') Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('/Users/zhihaowang/Desktop/untitled1.py', wdir='/Users/zhihaowang/Desktop')
>
> File
>   "/Users/zhihaowang/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py",
>   line 714, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "/Users/zhihaowang/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py",
>   line 89, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "/Users/zhihaowang/Desktop/untitled1.py", line 8, in 
>       from string import split
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'split'

Answer (score 0):

split is part of standard string method not from string module. Without importing also you could just apply split method. your_str.split()

Answer (score 0):

You don't import split, you just use it like:
`print("my comment".split())`
which returns `[my,comment]`

btw, split is at builtins , not string.
and you cant import it, the maximum you can do(which don't effects anything) is `from builtins import str`